# Login loop GUI three desktop environments

Tags: gnome, login, xorg, lightdm, gui

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and initially had problems with no GUI. After some help, I got Gnome and lightDM but now I am stuck in a login loop.

A while earlier I was able to login, but there were no Icons on the screen only the background. My login page shows three desktop environments, Gnome, and two Gnome on Xorg. I have tried the following codes already:

```
Sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

Sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

Sudo mv ~/.Xauthority

Sudo mv ~/. Xauthority~/.Xauthority.backup
```

None of these worked.

I am new to Ubuntu and just want to login. Please help.